# Custom Loading Icon in jqGrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Anyone have a good example of how to implement a custom loading icon while the grid is loading data instead of using the standard "Loading" box?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jqGrid trigger "Loading..." overlay](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705719/jqgrid-trigger-loading-overlay)

Answer (score 1):

You can probably find the answer on your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4473690/jqgrid-need-to-change-progress-message-loading/4474749#4474749).

Comment: Why not just mark this question as closed and point to the other question as an exact duplicate?

Comment: @JasCav: I prefer to be more friendly to people especially to the newcomer. I don't want to offend somebody. I mark questions as "close" only if the question is absolutely not for the stackoverflow.