# Replace default message "Loading..." to Image "Loading.gif" at JQGrid footer

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Experts,

I have implemented **JQGrid** with successfully on my project. **My requirement is i would like to replace default message "Loading..." to Image "Loading.gif" at jqgrid footer**.

**Is this possible to implement this?**

I have also attached screen shot for more clarity.

[image]

Updated JQGrid footer HTML
[image]

Thanks,
Imdadhusen

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all I recommend you to read two old answers: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705719/jqgrid-trigger-loading-overlay/2706447#2706447) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4473690/jqgrid-need-to-change-progress-message-loading/4474749#4474749).

To have the loading div which displays an animated gif and no text you should change the style of the 'loading' class for example like

```
<style type="text/css">
    .ui-jqgrid .loading {
        background: url(loader1.gif);
        border-style: none;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
</style>
```

remove the default text 'Loading...' with `$.jgrid.defaults.loadtext=''` and move the 'loading' div to the place where you want to have it. It con be needed to adjust some CSS styles additionally. For example

```
$("#load_list")
    .css({position:'relative',left:'0',float:'left',width:'4px',
          height:'4px','margin-top':'3px'})
    .prependTo('#pager_left');
```

At the end you will receive something like

[image]

See the corresponding demo [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/LoadingGifInPager.htm).

Comment: Awesome! Very helpful answer on jQGrid once again Oleg!

Comment: For those looking for a way to do something similar with FontAwesome rather than a gif.   Look at my answer here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4473690/jqgrid-need-to-change-progress-message-loading/47546944#47546944