# Why JQuery Modal Dialog and JQGrid Modal Dialog are looking different?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, modal-dialog

I have created JQGrid with Jquery modal dialog for Delete. Jqgrid with inline editing and one field is required if i leave it blank and the press submit the it will popup message Please enter First Name but the problem is Inbuilt Popup message and my jquery modal dialog are looking too different.

**Inbuilt JQGrid Modal Dialog:**
[image]

**JQuery Modal Dialog**
[image]

**CODE:**

```
function createGrid() {
        jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
            url: '@Url.Action("JQGridGetGridData", "TabMaster")',
            datatype: 'json',
            mtype: 'GET',
            colNames: ['col ID', 'First Name', 'Last Name', ''],
            colModel: [{ name: 'colID', index: 'colID', width: 100, align: 'left', searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'ne', 'cn']} },
                      { name: 'FirstName', index: 'FirstName', width: 150, align: 'left', editable: true, editrules: { required: true} },
                      { name: 'LastName', index: 'LastName', width: 150, align: 'left', editable: true, editrules: { required: true} },
                      { name: 'act', index: 'act', width: 60, sortable: false}],
            pager: jQuery('#pager'),
            hidegrid: false,
            rowNum: 100,
            rowList: [10, 50, 100, 150],
            sortname: 'colID',
            sortorder: "asc",
            viewrecords: true,
            multiselect: false,
            width: 500,
            height: "250px",
            imgpath: '@Url.Content("~/Scripts/themes/steel/images")',
            caption: 'Tab Master Information',
            editurl: '@Url.Action("JQGridEdit", "TabMaster")',
            gridComplete: function () {
                var ids = jQuery("#list").getDataIDs();
                for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
                    var id = ids[i];
                    be = "<a href='#'><div title='Edit' id='action_edit_" + id + "' class='actionEdit' onclick='inlineEdit(" + id + ");'></div></a>";
                    de = "<a href='#'><div title='Delete' id='action_delete_" + id + "' class='actionDelete' onclick='inlineDelete(" + id + ");'></div></a>";
                    se = "<a href='#'><div title='Save' style='display:none' id='action_save_" + id + "' class='actionSave' onclick='inlineSave(" + id + ");'></div></a>";
                    ce = "<a href='#'><div title='Cancel' style='display:none' id='action_cancel_" + id + "' class='actionCancel' onclick='inlineCancel(" + id + ");'></div></a>";
                    jQuery("#list").setRowData(ids[i], { act: be + de + se + ce })
                }
            }
        }).navGrid('#pager', { edit: false, add: false, del: false, search: false, refresh: false });
    }
```

**How can i apply Jquery Modal Dialog for JQGrid inbuilt dialog skin?**

Thanks,
Imdadhusen

Comment: What is about [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6646347/315935)? Do you read my answer?

Comment: I found your question interesting, so +1 from me and [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6693694/why-jquery-modal-dialog-and-jqgrid-modal-dialog-are-looking-different/6699428#6699428).

Comment: I checked $("#load_list") using firebug but i could not find any element in my jqgrid even there is no element from pager_left, pager_center and pager_right in my case so i assumed my jqgrid rendering are different from shown by you.

Comment: i have also submitted snap of my jqgrid footer and yours http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646347/replace-default-message-loading-to-image-loading-gif-at-jqgrid-footer.

Comment: I con't follow you. The original position of the #load_list are not in the pager, but you can move any element from the page to another place with respect of `jQuery.prependTo` for example. Is [my demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/LoadingGifInPager.htm) do what you need?

Comment: But i did not changed anything in my grid! i have added code for my jqgrid

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. What problem exactly which which from your grid you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jqGrid is jQuery plugin and not a jQuery UI widget. So it use not jQuery UI dialog. Instead of that it uses [$.jgrid.createModal](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.1.1/js/grid.common.js#L48), [$.jgrid.viewModal](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.1.1/js/grid.common.js#L158) and [$.jgrid.hideModal](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.1.1/js/grid.common.js#L21) method. In some situation simplified version [$.jgrid.info_dialog](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.1.1/js/grid.common.js#L182) are used. Many people (inclusive me) wish that jqGrid in one of the next version will do use more jQuery UI controls internally and probably will be a jQuery UI widget, but now if you want to create dialog in jqGrid style you should use the methods which I listed above.

As an example of usage of the functions I suggest [the following example](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/DeleteDialog0.htm) which create the same dialog as jqGrid do with [delGridRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing#delgridrow) method. I included in the demo the "Delete" navigation button to show, that if you first use "Delete selected row" button which create dialog and then use  "Delete" navigation button no new dialog will be created by jqGrid. Instead of that our custom dialog will be used.

The corresponding code is below:

```
var grid = $("#list"),
    gID = grid[0].id, //grid[0].p.id,
    IDs = {
        themodal:'delmod'+gID,
        modalhead:'delhd'+gID,
        modalcontent:'delcnt'+gID,
        scrollelm:'DelTbl_'+gID
    },
    hideDialog = function() {
        $.jgrid.hideModal("#"+IDs.themodal,{gb:"#gbox_"+gID,jqm:true, onClose: null});
    },
    rowId,
    createDeleteDialog = function() {
        var dlgContent =
            "<div id='"+IDs.scrollelm+"' class='formdata' style='width: 100%; overflow: auto; position: relative; height: auto;'>"+
                "<table class='DelTable'>"+
                    "<tbody>"+
                        "<tr id='DelError' style='display: none'>"+
                            "<td class='ui-state-error'></td>"+
                        "</tr>"+
                        "<tr id='DelData' style='display: none'>"+
                            "<td>"+rowId+"</td>"+ // it has not so much sense
                        "</tr>"+
                        "<tr>"+
                            "<td class='delmsg' style='white-space: pre;'>"+$.jgrid.del.msg+"</td>"+
                        "</tr>"+
                        "<tr>"+
                            "<td>&#160;</td>"+
                        "</tr>"+
                    "</tbody>"+
                "</table>"+
            "</div>"+
            "<table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' border='0' class='EditTable' id='"+IDs.scrollelm+"_2'>"+
                "<tbody>"+
                    "<tr>"+
                        "<td>"+
                            "<hr class='ui-widget-content' style='margin: 1px' />"+
                        "</td>"+
                    "</tr>"+
                    "<tr>"+
                        "<td class='DelButton EditButton'>"+
                            "<a href='javascript:void(0)' id='dData' class='fm-button ui-state-default ui-corner-all'>Delete</a>"+
                            "&#160;<a href='javascript:void(0)' id='eData' class='fm-button ui-state-default ui-corner-all'>Cancel</a>"+
                        "</td>"+
                    "</tr>"+
                "</tbody>"+
            "</table>";

        if ($('#'+IDs.themodal).length===0) {
            // dialog not yet exist. we need create it.
            $.jgrid.createModal(
                IDs,
                dlgContent,
                {
                    gbox: "#gbox_"+gID,
                    caption: $.jgrid.del.caption,
                    jqModal: true,
                    left: 12,
                    top: 44,
                    overlay: 10,
                    width: 240,
                    height: 'auto',
                    zIndex: 950,
                    drag: true,
                    resize: true,
                    closeOnEscape: true,
                    onClose: null
                },
                "#gview_"+gID,
                $("#gview_"+gID)[0]);
            $("#dData","#"+IDs.scrollelm+"_2").click(function(){
                // "Delete" button is clicked
                var rowId = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
                grid.jqGrid('delRowData',rowId);
                //$.jgrid.hideModal("#"+IDs.themodal,{gb:"#gbox_"+gID,jqm:true, onClose: null});
                hideDialog();
            });
            $("#eData", "#"+IDs.scrollelm+"_2").click(function(){
                // "Cancel" button is clicked
                //$.jgrid.hideModal("#"+IDs.themodal,{gb:"#gbox_"+gID,jqm:true, onClose: null});
                hideDialog();
                //return false;
            });
        }

        $.jgrid.viewModal("#"+IDs.themodal,{gbox:"#gbox_"+gID,jqm:true, overlay: 10, modal:false});
    };

grid.jqGrid({/*jqGrid options*/});

$("#delgridrow").click(function() {
    rowId = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
    if (rowId === null) {
        $.jgrid.viewModal("#alertmod",{gbox:"#gbox_"+grid[0].p.id,jqm:true});
        $("#jqg_alrt").focus();
    } else {
        createDeleteDialog();
    }

    return false;
});
```

Comment: @imdadhusen: It is reality. I just reduced the code used by jqGrid. You can reduce HTML code of the `dlgContent` if needed.

Comment: @imdadhusen: By the way if you will use `$.jgrid.del.caption` and `$.jgrid.del.msg` not directly and include as the parameter of the `createDeleteDialog` function you will have a "MessageBox" function which you can use. You should only probably replace call of `$.jgrid.hideModal` to call of [$.jgrid.closeModal](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.1.1/js/grid.common.js#L17)

Answer (score 1):

I too found the built-in jqGrid modal dialog difficult to implement. Trying to call the createModal(), with all of its parameters, was way too complicated. The workarounds I saw posted were also very complex. I decided to do an end-run around the problem by rewriting the HTML and then displaying it.

jqGrid already writes the HTML for their modal popup at load. I hijacked it, wrote my own listener for the 'X' close link and, lo and behold, I had myself a fully skinned dialog box. Mine isn't modal, but you could easily create your own by modifying the CSS of the solution. Once you understand how to manipulate the HTML you can add whatever elements/attributes/classes you want. Upon close you just remove what you've added.

```
var popup = function (msg, title) {
  if ($('#clonePopup').length == 0) {
    var popupClose = $('.ui-icon-closethick');
    popupClose.clone().attr('id', 'clonePopup').insertAfter(popupClose);
    popupClose.hide();
    $('#alertcnt>div').html(msg);
    $('#alerthd>span').html(title);
    $('#clonePopup').click(function (e) {
        $('#alertmod').hide();
        $('#clonePopup').remove();
        $('#alertcnt>div').html(' אנא, בחר שורה');
        $('#alerthd>span').html('אזהרה');
        popupClose.removeAttr('style');
    });
    $('#alertmod').show();
  }  
}};

popup('Row saved successfully','Success');
```

First, I test whether the messagebox is already displayed by checking if my #clonePopup id already exists. I then grab a handle on the X close link because I'm going to clone it and hide the original. If I use the original it won't work, because jqGrid is listening for it and I haven't set the necessary parameters. I create a clone and give it an ID of 'clonePopup'. I then hide the original.

```
$('#alertcnt>div') gets me the container for the title.
$('#alerthd>span') gets me the container for the message.
$('#alertmod') is then shown.

$('#clonePopup').click()  then resets the HTML to its original state to not interfere with jqGrid's normal operation.
```

It may not be a perfect solution but may be for some. Works for me. Saves me from trying to figure out how createModal() works!

The main point of this post is not whether this particular solution works for you as is (hopefully it does), but that you can override the limitations of jqGrid by rewriting their HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Update to my previous post...

I added a modal interface in the end which removed the need to check for my #clonePopoup. I clean up the modal at the end as well. I use a , found after the #alertmod  in Chrome, to create the modal. However, in IE, for some reason, this same  doesn't appear. I create it if it doesn't already exist.

Hopefully, this is a more complete solution.

```
var popup = function (msg, title) {
    var modalcss = { position: 'fixed', top: 0, left: 0, width: '100%', height: '100%', display: 'block', opacity: 0.4, filter: 'alpha(opacity=40)', 'background-color': '#000', 'text-align': 'center', 'z-index': 101 };
    var popupClose = $('.ui-icon-closethick');
    popupClose.clone().attr('id', 'clonePopup').insertAfter(popupClose);
    popupClose.hide();
  $('#alertcnt>div').html(msg);
    $('#alerthd>span').html(title);
    if ($('#tc_container').length) {
        $('#tc_container').css(modalcss);
    } else {
        $('<div>', { 'id': 'tc_container' }).css(modalcss).insertAfter($('#alertmod'));
    }

$('#clonePopup').click(function (e) {
    $('#alertmod').hide();
    $('#alertcnt>div').html(' אנא, בחר שורה');
    $('#alerthd>span').html('אזהרה');
    popupClose.removeAttr('style');
    $('#alertmod').css('display', '');
    $('#tc_container').attr('style', 'display:none;'); 
    $('#clonePopup').remove();
   });
   $('#alertmod').show();
};

popup('Row saved successfully','Success');
```